# How to share PC Internet over Wireless Router on Windows?

Tags: windows, router, ics

I just bought a Wireless Router that has 4 Ethernet LAN Ports and one WAN port. The manual that came along with the Router asks to connect a Broadband (Cable/xDSL) modem to the WAN port. However, I do **NOT** have a Broadband modem. I use a 4G USB modem to connect to the internet.

What I would like to do is share my Computers internet over the Wireless Router.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Opened "Network and Sharing Center" (I'm on Windows 8)
2. There are two adapters listed. One is the Computers Eternet adapter (I connected it to the WAN port of the Router) and the other is the USB Internet.
3. Right Clicked on the USB Internet adapter -> Properties -> Sharing -> (checked) Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection

**Expected Result:** I wanted to be able to connect my Samsung Tablet to the internet by using the Wireless Router. But it seems its not working. The router isn't *routing* Internet.

What am I doing wrong? I feel the solution is simple enough, but I am totally new to networking. This is my first attempt really.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

**EDIT:** After I did a bridge between the two connections, I lost internet connectivity. The following screenshot might help

[image]

With the bridge in place, I connected another PC to the router via an Ethernet cable. On that computer, IP addresses shown on the Router configuration page (192.168.1.2) seemed to be the right ones. However there was no internet connectivity on that computer as well.

Comment: Is the router set to get it's IP from your laptop (i.e. DHCP) or is it static?  You should be able to check in the Router's Setup-pages.  If this can even work (which it seems like it should), they would need to be on the same subnet.

Comment: I tried Automatic. If I try static, it gives me some forms to fill up. IP Address, Gateway, etc.

Comment: Looks like @SLaks got it for you, that makes sense.  And yes, you want automatic so you are good there I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have finally come up with the solution. It's simple really, as simple as anything! **Internet Connection Sharing** is the way to go. This is what I tried earlier, but it didn't work before due to some errors in the Router configuration.

- 4G Modem once connected will be shown in **Network Connections** as an Ethernet Adapter.
- The WAN port of the Router should be connected to the LAN port of the Computer.

[image]

1. Right click on the Adapter that is connected to the internet.
2. Select Properties.
3. Switch to the **Sharing** tab and check Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection
4. Its important to make sure that the router is configured to "Obtain IP Address automatically." This can usually be done by connecting the router to a PC via a LAN port and using the web browser. The details should be in the routers manual.

Comment: Close, but not quite there. The *LAN* port of the router should be connected to the LAN port of the computer. With this setup, the router isn't connected to any WAN. Connecting things this way will result in double NAT, which leads to all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Was trying to do the same thing.  I have a Wifi adapter on my PC that connected to my buildings wifi.  I needed to connect a printer to a router so I could print from my devices.  This is how I did it.

1. Set the router WAN to DCHP.
2. Plugged the Router WAN port into my PC's Ethernet port.
3. In the "Network Connects" settings I made sure that the "Share" was UNCHECKED for the wireless connection.
4. Selected the Unknown connection (Ethernet Adapter) and while holding down the Ctrl key single clicked on the Wireless adapter (highlighting both).
5. Right clicked one of them (doesn't matter which one) and selected "Create Bridge".

That was it.  Works great.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you enable ICS on NIC#1, and Windows sets your NIC#2 to 192.168.137.1, go to your router config page, and manually set the router's ip to 192.168.137.2 /255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.137.1

Leave the router DHCP on so that anyone who connects to the router will get a network IP address.
I don't think your computer will act as a dhcp server in this instance.

Also, the computer in between the modem and router is isolated from everyone on the router.

This is a semi-working solution. What I wanted was for everyone to be on the same network, but this method does not do that.
However, everyone does have access to the internet.

Comment: Router can also be on dynamic IP settings, which will do all the work, my tplink does it at least, just leave the NIC#2 to that IP you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to do same thing.I bought a 3G/4G Router (TP-Link MR3420)that has 4 Ethernet LAN Ports and one WAN port. The manual that came along with the Router asks to connect a Broadband (Cable/xDSL) modem to the WAN port. However, I do NOT have a Broadband modem. Initially I used a 4G USB modem to connect to the internet via router USB port but I needed to share My Mobile 4G internet with router via USB Tether. This is how I did it..

1.Connect the 4G phone to Laptop USB port and enable the USB tether on phone.In adapter setting lets refer this network as (Network#1).

2.Check the internet is working on laptop.

3. In the "Network Connects" settings I made sure that the "Share" was UNCHECKED for the Network#1.

4.Set the router WAN to DCHP.

5.Plugged the Router WAN port into my PC's Ethernet port.

6.Selected the Unknown connection (Ethernet Adapter) and while holding down the Ctrl key single clicked on the Wireless adapter (highlighting both).

7.Right clicked one of them (doesn't matter which one) and selected "Create Bridge".

Now from another laptop or mobile log in to router admin page under WAN setting Detect the WAN Connection Type and let it refresh the following settings
IP Address:
192.168.xx.xxx
Subnet Mask:
255.255.255.0
Default Gateway:
192.168.xx.yyy

In few minute you should notice WAN internet light getting green from amber. 
Enjoy your new 4G internet setup.

Answer (score 1):

MY answer to his issue:
to share "USB/tethered phone -internet" to a router on a LAN port so you will have access to the network group `<so your not on the WAN port>` will be same idea on Linux / Windows.

In this example I'll use 10.42.0.1 "default Linux shared-internet" as the computers IP address.

Windows 10 example:

1. Connect USB modem and Ethernet port to LAN on rougher
2. In network adapters select your Internet connection (USB modem / tethered phone) - in properties turn on internet connection sharing
3. In network adapters, select your network connection (Ethernet / LAN - open tcp/ip4 properties set Manual IP address to "10.42.0.1 / 255.255.255.0".
   **Note:**
   This is for you to remember the IP address for device setup...
   The default Windows address is 192.168.137.1 and is perfectly fine to use also, my example is for 0-config when switching OS's and computer's that are my internet device...
4. Device setup:

   Change the device connection to manual IP settings (disable DCHP) and then

   1. Set the IP-address to what you want it to be (192.168.10.69 or "10.42.0.2" /or 69.69.69.69) net-mask to `255.255.255.0`, "so they can see ether and the rest of group for networking"
   2. `<the important setting>` change set the Gateway to "10.42.0.1"
      **Note:**
      Some times you may have to also set a DNS to your internet server(10.42.0.1) and also a public DNS (1.1.1.1 // 8.8.8.8) this is rare on devices, but some times when having issues will fix the problem (some older LAN/ WiFi cards...   Remember to add both to DNS 1&2.

I hope that this might help some one else, my issue for the day was to share my tethered phone "easytether" and be able to be on the network to stream or share files, it took me a bit to figure it out , the only down side is you need to configure all devices that access the internet by manual IP settings...
The only alternative to use ways described by others using the WAN port is to create a VPN server/client "remote networking" to access your network.

Answer (score 0):

Here are correct settings(if "obtain IP auto" doesn't work for you)

1.Set USB modem(or any other network that has access to internet) as sharing and connect a cable to PC LAN RJ45 and router WAN interface.

2.LAN network connection- click properties-->ipv4 networking and set these parameters

IP 192.168.2.100

Netmask 255.255.255.0

everything else leaves empty

3. Open router web interface in a web browser (mostly 192.168.1.1 but may be different for your router like 192.168.0.1 ..etc) and set WAN settings to Static IP and set these parameters

IP 192.168.2.101

Netmask 255.255.255.0

Gateway 192.168.2.100

save...

That is it

Answer (score -1):

The method explained by Rakib Ansary works perfect. There is no issue of ip address assigning as mentioned by others. Let me explain how it happens in windows:

Suppose you have internet connectivity in Ethernet5, and you want to share it to Ethernet1. When sharing, windows automatically sets the IPv4 address of Ethernet1 to 192.168.137.1. (you need to connect the Ethernet1 LAN of PC to WAN of router, and set 'automatically get IP address' option in router settings).

Windows include a new virtual access point feature called Wireless Hosted Network. The default IP used by Windows is 192.168.137.1. However, you can change this IP to something else via Windows Registry changes.

Read more below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx?tduid=(0f4300904671015c5b0cdec004df9cec)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-jcY_Zuw.fFvRcHaZeflgPQ)()

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  You should edit this answer and provide specific and detailed steps on how the author solves their problem.  If you are going to provide a relevant within your answer, you should quote and cite the relevant information, your answer by itself does not currently answer the author's question