# How to Share Laptop internet to router via ethernet port

Tags: networking, router, wan, internet-sharing

How to Share Laptop internet to router via ethernet port. Laptop is also connected with another wifi network so how we can share that internet from laptop to router. In which port on router (WAN or LAN) we have to connect from laptop?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it following this answer:
[How to share PC Internet over Wireless Router on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/497165/how-to-share-pc-internet-over-wireless-router-on-windows)

However there is another way. You can create a [hotspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_(Wi-Fi)) with your laptop.
Here is a guide to Windows 7 and 8 http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/

A video tutorial for Windows 7/8/10 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh6gbrnYzS0

And a guide to Ubuntu http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Comment: 1st link is doesn't work. i have to share internet to router only. because my laptop hotspot is doesn't work

Comment: @DarshitPatel - all links work for me

Comment: links is work but the sollution is not worked

Answer (score 1):

With Win 7(pretty sure it's the same in Win 8), when you have the wifi signal and the Ethernet plugged in to the router, go to Network and Sharing Center, on the left there is a Change Adapter Settings, the select the wifi adapter and the Ethernet adapter together with Ctrl.  Right Click one of them and there should be a Bridge Connections option, this will send your wifi to the cable.

Comment: Your solution worked! I am able to connect to the wifi network through my smartphone but not able to access any webpage (Wifi symbol has an "!" in it).

Comment: Can you still get internet on the bridged laptop?

Comment: yes, it is working in my laptop.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct 2 adapters chosen and bridged.  Undo the bridge, make sure you still have wifi internet.  Redo the bridge.  [this link][1] says that 'Share Internet' should be UNCHECKED, weird but worth a try


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/497165/how-to-share-pc-internet-over-wireless-router-on-windows?lq=1

Comment: Yes i tried this but it also not worked. In router the internet light is on and showing internet connection = GOOD but still the internet is not working on mobile (via Wifi).

Comment: Can you try a different device attached to the newly bridged wifi?  it could be something from the mobile.  Is there a reason you aren't connecting the mobile to this shared wifi?

Comment: yes i tried with different mobile but in other phone also the internet is not working

Comment: What i want to do is at my office the company wifi is given to me via wifi in laptop so i want to share that wifi from laptop to router. Is there any need of cross cable in order to share my laptop internet to router?

Comment: By wifi in laptop do you mean a cellular card?

Comment: No cellular card

Comment: Can you connect another laptop to the router and see what windows says in troubleshooting? Why don't you use the company wifi for your mobile?

Comment: It is prohibited to use in mobile phone.

Comment: If you can test with another laptop we will know whether or not they are blocking the phone and its protocols or if there is a problem with the bridge to the router.  Either way, if it's against policy, putting a router between your mobile and their network is still against policy.  On the security side, unless you know how to lock down that router, you are creating a backdoor into your companies network.

Comment: Okay i will do that thing in next 10 minutes. But i can't understand why are you saying about bridge. The sharing of internet is from laptop to router is possible via sharing tab in wifi property. By the way it is not working and also not showing a internet connection in router. But in bridge router is showing internet connection but not working in mobile.

Comment: No it's is  also not working in other laptop.

Comment: Process of elimination is all I was saying about the bridge.  So it is in the router.  what is the IP address of your corporate connected laptop? and what is the IP of the mobile or laptop connected to the router?

Answer (score 0):

WAN is where the internet input should go.
This might be redundant but anyways:
You can share your internet connection if you go to the Network and sharing center, go to Network adapters, select your Wifi adapter, right-click and go to Properties, go to the "Sharing" tab, tick the top "Allow ..." (probably untick the bottom "Allow ..."), select you wired network adapter from the dropdown (probably listed as "Local Area Connection")

Comment: In which port on router (WAN or LAN) i have to connect from laptop?

Comment: WAN on the router, after you shared your connection

Comment: After i shared my wifi from laptop, router doesn't showing internet connection.

Comment: maybe you need to use a crossover cable?  the "normal" cable is patch or straight through

Comment: Unless the router is like 10 years old it should be able to automatically set crossover or straight-through

Comment: can you maybe test if it works on a different laptop or computer? i mean instead of the router, share the connection with a different computer. check the connectino sharing options if it's not working (you need to select the correct interface for it work)

Comment: i can't understand your answer. So plz give me whole solution.