# How can i use my laptops WiFi and give it to a router via Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I want to make my own access point, using my laptop's WiFi as the Internet source, with a router I have on hand, but I'm not sure how to configure it.

I read some posts here and found similar questions a few years old (e.g., [How to Share Laptop internet to router via ethernet port](https://superuser.com/questions/1042460/how-to-share-laptop-internet-to-router-via-Ethernet-port))

I'm not sure what to plug the Ethernet cable in; some people say to plug it into the WAN port of the router;  others say plug it into a LAN port of the router.  I now have a bridged connection with a TP-Link USB WiFi adapter plugged into the LAN port.

When i connect to the network via WiFi on my phone it works (not sure about connecting to website but Instagram works completely)but on my PC it shows that it has wifi but if i search something up it just keeps loading (on pc it says This site can’t be reached www.google.com’s server IP address could not be found.) and that goes for not being able to search stuff up on my phone (the YouTube app doesn't work) but some other apps like Instagram, Tiktok. but discord, YouTube and snapchat don't work. i'll provide pictures of the setup and settings. the router is relatively old (around 2010) here are some pictures i took showing the routers gateway settings and a picture from my laptop as well as how it's set up. (these are all the pictures showing the router's GUI, network bridge on my laptop and the setup of the router to my laptop. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHgNf.jpg)

Comment: Ok so after not changing my network to my main home network for a little i finally did and i got a crap load of messages from chats on instagram indicating that i can send messages and receive messages on my main wifi but it's really slow on the router in my room. hope that shines some light on it.

Comment: (update, i'm wrong and just did a test to see the latency of messages. at the start it took a little bit but about a minute later it started to come instantly with no delay so that's good to know. and considering it's an old router and hasn't been used in years it's understandable about the latency)

Answer (score 0):

The network you connected to with your phone is the upstream wifi or the one provided by your router?
As for connecting the ethernetcable just think of it like this: WAN ports interconnect separate network, LAN ports work like a switch.
This means that if you use the WAN port, your router will also have to provide all the basic services like DNS, DHCP etc. All of this will only work if your laptop is properly forwarding the packets from the downstream network.
As for the different behaviour between apps like instagram and browsing the web: I know that some of Facebooks apps will work even in networks without DNS, since they will fallback to a list of IP addresses..
If you say that you succeeded in getting "some" traffic into the internet I would start in the downstream subnet and work myself upwards all layers: Check DHCP offer / client configuration, ping router, ping public IP (e.g. 1.1.1.1), ping public IP using name (e.g. google.com).

Comment: Alright i'll try some of that, i'm not that fond of all of this considering i'm 15 and i don't have that much knowledge, but i'll try to make the best of what you said. thank you

Comment: and my phone was getting the wifi from the router in my room not the router from my isp

Comment: alright so i did some of the things you mentioned and i should probably tell you the outcome i got.

to start, i do get allocated ip's for my devices ie,. my phone, laptop, pc etc..

so i am getting DHCP offers, i'm also able to ping my router but i can't ping my public ip nor my public ip name because on the router in my room is only running off of internal ip addresses aka 

My MAC Address for the router
The connection : Static ip
IP Adress :192.168.0.1
the Subnet Mask : 255.255.0.0
Then the default gateway and the dns : 192.168.0.1

Comment: The subnet mask should probably be a "/24 " or (255.255.255.0)

Comment: alright for sure, i'll change that. ty